# My item renderer is not finding property "data."

Tags: flash, apache-flex, button, adobe, itemrenderer

I'm trying to create a custom button renderer for my list and it keeps saying unidentified property "data." Here is my code.

Renderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Button xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" label="{data.label}">
</s:Button>
```

Object calling the renderer:

```
<s:List x="80" y="88" width="142" height="384" dataProvider="{navigation}" itemRenderer="com.renderers.NavigationRenderer" borderVisible="false"/>
```

And the array collection holding the data for the list:

```
[Bindable]
private var navigation:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    {label:"Home",state:"Home"},{label:"Tools",state:"Tools"}
]);
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spark button does not implement the IDataRenderer interface.

You could easily place your button inside an ItemRenderer class to get access to that interface, or you could create a new item renderer class that extends Button and implements IDataRenderer.

Answer (score 4):

Does the s:Button have a property named data?

Have your renderer extend the ItemRenderer class.  [More information here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS03d33b8076db57b9-23c04461124bbeca597-8000.html).

Your renderer should be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:ItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
          xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
          xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" >
<s:Button label="{data.label}">
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Spark components don't have the *data* property by default. To use a component as an inderer it should implement the [IItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/IItemRenderer.html) interface, which the spark Button doesn't.